# Delphi - socket error 10038 at startup. How solve it?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I get socket error 10038 at startup.

[image]

How solve this error?

Answer (score 10):

This is a common error. Try this:

1. shut the IDE down.
2. run regedit.
3. go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\21.0\KnownIDE Packages`
4. find the entry `$(BDS)\Bin\LivePreview270.bpl` and change the data from `"Embarcadero FireUI Live Preview Package"` to `"__Embarcadero FireUI Live Preview Package"` (so, just add two underscores in front of the text)
5. start the IDE.

Comment: Magic! :-) ....

Comment: Thanks, saved me a reinstall...
Happened after patching 11.2 via GetIt- shouldn't have touched 10.4!

Comment: Just got that error and the answer still works - much appreciated